# Haskell or Ocaml with OpenGL and SDL precompiled distribution for Windows

Tags: windows, opengl, haskell, ocaml, sdl

I want to learn Ocaml or Haskell and I want to do it by writing a simple game. Apparently, there's one small problem: nobody cares about Windows and I want to do it on Windows, natively.

Haskell has Cabal, which has SDL, but it doesn't build due to a trivial problem with no workarounds (order of parameters passed to gcc). Ocaml doesn't even have that, it's all in source packages, be it GLCaml or OcamlSDL or whatever.

Is there a place where I can get a working SDL for Haskell or Ocaml on Windows without fighting with a dozen versions of compilers?

Comment: Godi and OASIS are two Cabal-like systems for OCaml, but I am not proposing them as answers because I do not know how well they work under Windows.

Comment: That's really a hell of a problem, I faced the same issue a year ago, but gave up and designed my game under Ubuntu with OCamlSDL, here's a link to the game if interested http://web.martani.net/worms

Comment: Start with the Haskell Platform for Windows: http://haskell.org/platform

Answer (score 5):

The Haskell Platform comes with a binding to OpenGL which should work out of the box on Windows.

Concerning the SDL package on hackage, you can use `cabal unpack SDL` to get the source code and fix things yourself. To install the package with your changes, run `cabal install` in the unpacked directory. In any case, drop a line to the maintainer, I'm sure he'll help out.

Comment: the problem AFAIK isn't even in the package; [here's a more detailed explanation](http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.com/2010/05/haskell-sdl-on-windows-check-hacking.html).

Comment: Ah, yuck! The problem that the SDL library redefines your `main` function with a CPP macro. The actual `main` function is in the DLL! This is probably why the linker arguments have to be interchanged. In short, the blame lies with libSDL, whose design doesn't play well with any kind of foreign interface.

Comment: I guess your only recourse is to temporarily install a custom version of hsc2hs with JP Moresau's fix. Or you can be really sneaky and replace GCC with a wrapper program that interchanges the arguments before passing them to the real GCC.

Comment: And even once you have hsSDL installed, the fun continues, because SDL expects to work its CPP macro magic on applications using it, which works not so well if the entry point is Haskell's `main`. The easiest solution there seems to be exporting your real `main` through the FFI, and calling it from a small C wrapper that SDL can mangle as it pleases.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to SDL, but you've mentioned OpenGL. There is [LablGL](http://wwwfun.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/soft/lsl/lablgl.html) binding for OpenGL in OCaml which works out of the box. Wiki example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_Caml#Triangle_.28graphics.29) compiles and works just fine.

Comment: It seems that it only supports the ancient variant of OpenGL - I don't see vertex/fragment programs, etc.

Comment: @Baczek: As I said in my answer, the GLCaml bindings do support vertex and fragment shaders and I have used them. However, if you intend to distribute what you write I would advise against using either OCaml or Haskell for this.

Answer (score 1):

The best instructions I've found for getting SDL to work in windows with a the most recent Haskell platform can be found at [this blog](http://web.animal-machine.com:8080/blog/2010/04/a-haskell-adventure-in-windows/).  I followed everything step-by-step and it worked perfectly, despite some configure error messages.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't SDL but GLFW works on Windows with Haskell through Cabal.

Answer (score 0):

My article [High-fidelity graphics with OpenGL 2](http://ocamlnews.blogspot.com/2008/02/high-fidelity-graphics-with-opengl-2.html) (25th Feb 2008) explained how the [GLCaml](http://glcaml.sourceforge.net/) bindings can be used to write OpenGL-based applications in OCaml that use vertex and fragment shaders (a phong shader is given as an example). There are [9 articles](http://ocamlnews.blogspot.com/search/label/opengl) in the OCaml Journal on OpenGL, albeit mostly using the older [LablGL](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/soft/olabl/lablgl.html) library for OpenGL 1.1.

I tried and failed to get OpenGL working from Haskell under Linux in 2007. The [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) may have changed that but I have neither had time to try it yet myself nor ever heard of anyone using it for this.

However, both OCaml and Haskell must rely upon fragile low-level bindings to OpenGL because they are standalone languages and *nobody has ever managed to get any significant commercial software using them to work*. As you're on Windows, F#+XNA is a far more logical choice because XNA is tried and tested and F# has a safe high-level interface to it. A Google fight gives you a good idea of what a pioneer you'll be: [+haskell +opengl](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%2Bhaskell+%2Bopengl#q=%2Bhaskell+%2Bopengl&hl=en&prmd=iv&ei=bGvpTPXFL8GIhQfwq_iZCQ&start=450&sa=N&fp=a9e938379f07d4dc) gives 437 hits on Google and [+ocaml +opengl](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%2Bhaskell+%2Bopengl#q=%2Bocaml+%2Bopengl&hl=en&prmd=iv&ei=tGvpTLirJtCGhQftyf0O&start=360&sa=N&fp=a9e938379f07d4dc) gives only 347 hits.

Comment: Unfortunate that the most pragmatic answer, especially the last paragraph, gets downvoted.